# Missing Node in a Pattern in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Just wanna ask about neo4j. Suppose I have 
3 nodes:

1. (A:Node {name:A})
2. (B:Node {name:B})
3. (C:Node {name:C})

Which has a relationship like this: A-[:RELATED]->B-[:RELATED_TO]->C.

My question is how to know if there is a missing node in the pattern and return it's name?

Thanks,
Fed

Answer (score 1):

I think you could make use of an optional match to do that:

```
MATCH (A:Node {name: "A"}
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (A)-[:RELATED]->(B:Node {name: "B"})
WITH A, path
WHERE path is null
RETURN A
```

That would show you the 'A' nodes which don't have a 'RELATED' relationship to B.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I have another concern.. What if B node is not existing at all? and I want to display the label of missing node. 

For ex. I have pattern like (a:LetterA)--(b:LetterB)

but b node is missing and I want to display it's label that LetterB is missing. Thanks

Comment: you can use coalesce(labels(B),"None")